# Ресурсы, содержащие текстовые файлы

Tags: java

Я создал проект в IDEA. У меня есть ресурсы: изображения (png) и текстовые файлы (txt). В программе я работаю с картинками так

```
URL url = MyClass.class.getResource(shortName); 
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(url);
```

Всё работает хорошо. Но если попробую таким же образом получить URL для текстового файла-ресурса, то он будет равен `Null`. Оказалось, что программа берет ресурсы из директории с классами (class-файлы) и туда почему-то при компиляции копируются файлы с расширением png, а текстовые файлы - нет. Как исправить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обращайся к ним относительно папки bin и положи все ресурсы в папку resource, а вместо простой компиляции лучше создай простенький ant-скрипт который будет собирать jar-архив и запускать его.

Структура папок:

```
Project
 |
 |--ant
 |   |
 |   -- build.xml
 |--bin
 |--lib
 ---src
```

build.xml:

```
<project default="main" basedir="..">
    <tstamp>
        <format property="now" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss" />
    </tstamp>

    <target name="main" depends="compile">
        <checksum totalproperty="version_md5">
            <fileset dir="bin" />
        </checksum>
        <antcall target="makeJar"><param name="jarName" value="executableJAR"/></antcall>
    </target>

    <target name="compile">
        <javac srcdir="src"  destdir="bin" classpath=".">
            <classpath>
                <fileset dir="lib">
                    <include name="**/*.jar"/>
                </fileset>
            </classpath>
        </javac>
    </target>

    <target name="makeJar">
        <jar basedir="bin" destfile="jars/context_${jarName}.jar" encoding="utf8">
            <include name="**/*.class" />
            <manifest>
                <attribute name="Bundle-Version" value="${version_md5}" />
                <attribute name="Class-Path" value="lib/SOME_LIB.jar"/>
                <attribute name="Main-Class" value="package.${jarName}"/>
            </manifest>
        </jar>
    </target>    
</project>
```

Comment: А без Ant никак?